# When asking about acronyms, should each acronym be in its own question?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

My little brother asked a question earlier about acronyms and code terms in Rise of Nations. However people have said that each one should be precise (where did he hear it, why did he hear it, what topic was it on). Should each code term receive its own question?

Comment: Please use a title better suited towards our Q&A format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it *acceptable* to do this? Strictly speaking, it's within the rules, yes, and not worthy of closure.

That said, I downvoted both questions, and I did it for a reason;

Word salad list questions like this, with no context, no content, are a pretty perfect example of *not showing research effort*, along with being *unclear* and *not terribly useful*.

Is it *required* that you split it up? No.

Is asking ten *great*, detailed terminology questions, with context and background, which elicit good answers better than asking one *terrible* terminology question that looks like an intoxicated chihuahua walked across the keyboard?

You bet your ass it is.

Comment: +1 for intoxicated chihuahuas!

Answer (score 3):

Nope, it's perfectly fine to group a single game's jargon into a single question.

One of our better examples: [For League of Legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/32299/336)

Comment: That League of Legends question is an atrocity.

Comment: [Here's the chat transcript from last night where we were discussing the questions at issue.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/conversation/on-dictionaries-and-stuff)